# ambiguity about a human or a window

Tags: clauses, ambiguity

> The following day, as twilight was falling, she stood at the window **overlooking** the Yard.

Would you tell me if this sentence has an ambiguity?

I think it does. Is **she** overlooking, or is **the window** overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there's no ambiguity.

> The following day, as twilight was falling, she stood at the window
>   overlooking the Yard.

This implies she stood at the **window overlooking** the yard. Here, **she** wasn't overlooking the yard, the **window** was.

What I think you are referring to as the ambiguity, is when **she** would be overlooking the yard. In such a case, you would normally see a comma, before overlooking, like:

> The following day, as twilight was falling, she stood at the window,
>   overlooking the Yard.